# Different style for groups in WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In my app on main page I have 3 groups (SampleDataGroup) and each group has one item. Now, for all groups I use `Standard250x250ItemTemplate` style.

How can I use different style for each group?

Does it really switch styles in code?

For e.g

```
    If (someCondition)
    {//use styleOne} 
    else 
    { //use styleTwo}
```

Comment: Perhaps DataTemplateSelector solves your problem? Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector

Comment: Additional, this is a good article about DataTemplateSelector:http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/data-template-selector-in-windows-8-metro-xaml-app/

Comment: Yes, it's solve my problem, but not all. For e.g I have one group with two Items. I set Images for Items in SampleDataSource constructor(I use grid template). Can I change Images for Items by `DataTemplateSelector` ?

Comment: On your GridView, notice that there are two Selector properties: GroupStyleSelector and ItemTemplateSelector. Use the GroupStyleSelector to style the group, and the ItemTemplateSelector to make your item templates (like your images).